# limiting text in a table, showing all on the mouse move

Tags: html-table

I have a table which receives dynamic data (texts), sometimes the cell texts are big and it ruins the layout.
I would like to limit the number of characters in a cell of the table ( maybe in 10 caracters ) and move the mouse, display characters completely or balloon warning with full text.
May be in jquery or css.

I searched and not found anything.

example:

( A )

text text text
text text text

how I wish it were ( B )

text text text...

to hover, show the entire text of this cell ( B ) --> ( A )

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

On hover you overwrite it with the normal behavior. You will also need the overflow property for this.